# PowerShell in C#: Unable to load DLL wldp.dll

Tags: c#, powershell

I am getting an error when attempting to run the following in C#.

The error is:

> Exception:Thrown Unable to load DLL wldp.dll

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-BrokerSession");
ps.AddParameter("AdminAddress");
ps.AddParameter("MYSERVERNAMEHERE");
Collection<PSObject> psr = ps.Invoke();
```

It's also saying that `Get-BrokerSession` is not a recognized command, yet I can use this at the PS command prompt without issue.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have to load the Citrix-specific PowerShell modules. if your PS version is 3.0.
this should resolve error:
 **Get-BrokerSession is not a recognized command** 

then you can move to the next step.

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { @"C:\Temp\PSModule.psm1" });  // + Include in your PSModule.psm1: function ImportCitrixModule { Asnp Citrix* }
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
initial.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
runspace.Open();
RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new  RunspaceInvoke(runspace); 
runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.AddCommand("ImportCitrixModule"); // +
Collection<PSObject> psr = ps.Invoke();
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately. It runs into too many errors trying to load all those modules. I find it frustrating that I can't just load them on the server I am running the app from and have it work from the code. I can load the modules just find without error in the powershell command line, I can run the command and it works, it just won't do it when I run it from C#.

Comment: I have updated the code with some changes just to check importing module part. I don't have the Citirix PS module installed on my computer so try if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://sammyageil.com/post/stump-the-chump-resolving-unable-to-load-dll-wldp-dll-exception) it can help to check Prefer 32-bit in the project build settings.

I ran into this error when trying to start an executable file via C# Powershell in a UnitTest project. You cannot select this option for UnitTest projects (so it didn't help me) but running my test without debugging it works as intended. I ended up not having a UnitTest/IntegrationTest...